403 forbidden error when use helm push command in AWS ECR
I tried to follow the AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/push-oci-artifact.html) to push a helm chart to AWS ECR.
I created the ECR repo name, and the name is same as the helm chart name.
However, when I issued the 'helm push' command, I got an error message "

Error: unexpected status from HEAD request to
https://xxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v2/sit-helm-chart/manifests/0.1.1:
403 Forbidden

".
The helm version is:

version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.15.2",
GitCommit:"1a500d5625419a524fdae4b33de351cc4f58ec35",
GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.22.4"}

The aws cli version is:

aws-cli/2.16.12 Python/3.11.8 Linux/6.1.92-99.174.amzn2023.x86_64
exe/x86_64.amzn.2023

The ec2 instance that I used to issue this helm command has the proper IAM role to push docker images and helm to ECR.
Is there any other reason for this error? How to solve this error?
Here are the pictures for reference:



I found that it is actually because of the IAM policy attached to the ec2 instance. The ec2 instance is missing the correct IAM policy.
After attaching this policy to it, the helm push command can be run without error.

